compare numpy array against list of values
I would like to have your help about a problem I have with a numpy array.
In my code I have a huge array made of integers, this is the result of a skimage labelling process.
The idea is that I want to generate a boolean array with same shape as the input array containing a True value if the cell value belong to a given list of good labels, and false otherwise.
It is much easier with a small example:
import numpy as np
input_array = np.arange(15, dtype=np.int64).reshape(3, 5)
good_labels = [1, 5, 7]
mask_output = np.zeros(input_array.shape).astype(int)
for l in good_labels:
    masked_input = (input_array == l).astype(int)
    mask_output += masked_input
mask_output = mask_output > 0

This code works, but it is extremely slow because input_array is huge and good_labels is also very long, so I need to loop too much.
Is there a way to make it faster?
I was thinking to replace the whole loop with something like
mask_output = input_array in good_labels

But this does not work as expected.
Can you help me?

Do you have no control over the labels? It would be a lot easier if you made all the good labels consecutive.  I can't think of a simple answer to the actual question you asked.

yeah unless you can play tricks like suggested above, you have to do n_label * n_elem comparisons no mater what, if these numbers are large, I would assume the overhead of doing one loop in native python will be negligible...

looping through labels could be multithreaded?

unfortunately I cannot make the label consecutives. The labels are generated by skimage segmentation and then I am applying some selection criteria to them to obtain the good  label list.
Theoretically the looping can be multithreaded. each thread can generate a masked_input matrix and when they are all finished, I sum all of them before converting the output in a bool matrix. Not sure I am able to code though...

not sure i'm understanding your question. have you tried isin?

@diggusbickus, indeed this is the right answer. I have marked Vinod Baste's answer below has correct.

You could try numpy.isin.
mask_output = np.isin(input_array,good_labels)


Thanks, this is actually doing exactly what I had in mind. Effective and fast!
